# Realtime console redirection issue

Tags: vb.net, real-time, console-redirect

First of all, I did spend quite some time trying to find an answer to my issue but so far, nothing.

Here is the issue.
I have to run a cli command with arguments and redirect the output (REALTIME) to a textbox.
The command will look like this:
smcli - n name -f "script.scr"

Since smcli is not in the system PATH variable, I first need to go to the right Dir

So, I end up running the full command that looks like this:
cmd /c cd "c:\Program Files(x86)\bla\" && smcli - n name -f "script.scr"

I'll put the code in one sec but basically, the thing is working just fine, I get to the correct directory, run the command, it runs the script, all good.

I tried to redirect the output to a different form but then it doen't work anymore at all; anyway, that would be the bonus question.

The thing is though, when the script runs, it does say step by step what it is doing and sends that info to the output (i.e. restoring the name, restoring the disk config, ...)

As I said, I do get all those outputs....once EVERYTHING is completed (i.e. after 5 minutes of apparent freeze).
NOT redirecting the output to the textbox (i.e. leaving the console window open), I get the output real time.

So here is the code now (there is a bit of it, sorry):

```
Private Sub ReadMDcfgToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReadMDcfgToolStripButton.Click
        Dim exitcode As Int32
        smcli = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles") & "\Dell\MD Storage Manager\client\" 'SMcli.exe"
        Dim gotosmclidir As String = "cd """ & smcli & """"
        Dim smclicommand As String
            smclicommand = "smcli -n " & mdname & " -c ""save storagearray configuration file=\""" & saveFileDialog2.FileName & "\"" allconfig"";"
            cmd = gotosmclidir & " && " & smclicommand
            exitcode = RunCommandCom(cmd, "", False)
End Sub

Private Function RunCommandCom(command As String, arguments As String, permanent As Boolean) As Int32
    ' Usage:
    'RunCommandCom("DIR", "/W", true)
    'For the multiple command on one line the key are the & | && and || command connectors
    '•A & B -> execute command A, then execute command B. 
    '•A | B -> execute command A, and redirect all it's output into the input of command B.
    '•A && B -> execute command A, evaluate the errorlevel after running Command A, and if the exit code (errorlevel) is 0, only then execute command B.
    '•A || B -> execute Command A, evalutate the exit code of this command and if it's anything but 0, only then execute command B.

    TextBox1.Text = "Communication in progress..." & vbCrLf
    exitcodelbl.Text = ""
    CmdCloseBtn.Enabled = False
    ToolStrip1.Enabled = False
    CmdOutputPanel.Visible = True

    Dim p As Process = New Process()
    Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()


    pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    pi.Arguments = " " + If(permanent = True, "/K", "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments
    MsgBox(pi.Arguments)
    pi.CreateNoWindow = True
    pi.UseShellExecute = False
    pi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    pi.RedirectStandardError = True
    pi.CreateNoWindow = True
    p.StartInfo = pi
    AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf GotData
    p.Start()
    p.BeginOutputReadLine()

    Do Until p.HasExited
    Loop

    exitcodelbl.Text = p.ExitCode
    Select Case p.ExitCode
        Case 0
            exitcodelbl.Text += " - Command completed successfully."
        Case 1
            exitcodelbl.Text += " - Could not communicate with the Array."
        Case 9
            exitcodelbl.Text += " - Could not communicate with the Array."
        Case 14
            exitcodelbl.Text += " - Could not communicate with the Array."
        Case Else
            exitcodelbl.Text += " - Unknown code."
    End Select
    Return p.ExitCode
End Function

Sub GotData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    UpdateTextBox(e.Data)
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxDelegate(ByVal Text As String)

Private Sub UpdateTextBox(ByVal Tex As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim del As New UpdateTextBoxDelegate(AddressOf UpdateTextBox)
        Dim args As Object() = {Tex}
        Me.Invoke(del, args)
    Else
        TextBox1.Text &= Tex & Environment.NewLine
    End If
End Sub
```

Apart from the command itself, everything else is comming from researches and they are just put together, the way to run the command on one hand and the redirection on the other hand.

I believe the issue is with my command (looks like that part is VERY sensible).

Either I can have it done a different way (again, it works but not real time) or I missed something trivial...?

Thanks for your help.

Following tinstaafl here is the updated code:

```
Private Sub MainForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    copyrightlbl.Focus()
    wait(1000)
    Await RunCommandCom("", "192.168.219.152", False) '172.16.1.55
    CmdCloseBtn.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Async Function RunCommandCom(command As String, arguments As String, permanent As Boolean) As Task(Of Int32)
    TextBox1.Text = "Communication in progress..." & vbCrLf
    exitcodelbl.Text = ""
    CmdCloseBtn.Enabled = False
    ToolStrip1.Enabled = False
    CmdOutputPanel.Visible = True

    Dim p As Process = New Process()
    With p.StartInfo
        .WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles") & "\Dell\MD Storage Manager\client\" 'Directory for SMcli.exe"
        .FileName = "ping.exe"
        .Arguments = command + " " + arguments
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
    End With

    p.Start()

    Do Until p.HasExited
        TextBox1.Text &= Await p.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync
    Loop
    exitcodelbl.Text = p.ExitCode
    Return p.ExitCode
End Function
```

Comment: If the script is meant to be run in a console, can't you just run it in it's own console instead of using a cmd console?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I probably can't because 1) I have to run the command from a specific path so have to navigate to it first  and 2) that cli based application is not in the PATH var from Windows (and no, I can't have it added because I would change the Windows configuration and that's a complete NO-NO)

Comment: You can set the whole path to the executable in the Filename property.  No need for trying to use the PATH or to navigate anywhere.  If the executable needs to a specific Working Directory, set that also in the startInfo properties

Comment: that helps in the sense that I do not need to run command 1 && command2 anymore. It is clearly a step forward. I also tried to use pi.FileName = "ping.exe" with pi.Arguments = "192.168.0.1". It is generating an output in my textbox as expected but still not realtime. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a delegate try reading the output directly to the textbox.  The `StandardOutput` property of the Process is a stream that you can use the ReadLineAsync method to get the output.  Something like this should work:

```
pi.CreateNoWindow = True
pi.UseShellExecute = False
pi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
pi.RedirectStandardError = True
p.StartInfo = pi
p.Start()

Do Until p.HasExited
   TextBox1.Text &= Await p.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync
Loop
```

Intellisense will prompt you to make the sub routine Async, but with that you should get the output you want.

```
Private Async Function RunCommandCom(command As String, arguments As String, permanent As Boolean) As Task(Of Int32)


Await RunCommandCom("", "192.168.219.152", False)
```

Comment: Indeed, I got this: Error 'Await' can only be used within an Async method. Consider marking this method with the 'Async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task(Of Integer)'. Excuse my ignorance but how to deal with it. Again, tried to look that up but do not understand what I'm reading because the way it works is outside my knowledge.

Comment: The Async modifier goes before the function or sub keyword

Comment: I'm sory but you lost me guys. :-(

Comment: I added a sample of where the Async modifier goes.

Comment: this is unknown teritory for me. looked around for examples and came accross this: [link](http://www.vbvoorbeelden.be/Asynchrone-Code-Async-en-Await.vb) Did a copy/paste of the code which is believed to be valid and I'm getting an error on this line: `Dim pingStatus As String = Await pingStatusTask` And the error is "'Await' can only be used within an Async method. Consider marking this method with the 'Async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task(Of Integer)'" I don't get it.... :-(

Comment: did you follow the example I gave you?

Comment: I do not understand it I'm afraid

Comment: I edited my last sample to more closely mimic your code.  If that doesn't make it any plainer I'm at a loss as to how make it any simpler.

Comment: right, NOW I'm with you, simple....but...
`    Private Sub MainForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        copyrightlbl.Focus()
        wait(1000)
        RunCommandCom("", "192.168.219.152", False) '172.16.1.55
        CmdCloseBtn.Enabled = True
    End Sub`

Comment: `        Do Until p.HasExited
            TextBox1.Text &= Await p.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync
        Loop
        exitcodelbl.Text = p.ExitCode
        Return p.ExitCode
    End Function`


Now I'm getting the following warning in **MainForm_Shown** for _RunCommandCom()_:Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the Await operator to the result of the call.I'm also getting errors on each call for the function:
Value of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Integer)' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.

Comment: First off it's very hard to read code in the comments.  Edit your post, then put a comment in saying that's what you've done. When you call the sub routine add the `Await` modifier to it as well.  I added another example to my answer.

Comment: Edited the first post with the code.
I can't thank you enough with your help thus far; once I'll have a working code, I'll be able to review it, understand it and be truly greatful that you helped me make it work.
new error when calling the function:
'Await' can only be used when contained within a method or lambda expression marked with the 'Async' modifier

Comment: the `MainForm_Shown` needs the `Async` modifier.  basically each await modifier needs and async modifier and each async modifier needs at least one await modifier.

Comment: NOW I understand your frustration. Was soooo clean and simple. Thank you very VERY much for your help.
You're my hero tinstaafl